# C# equivalent of the C++ std::vector::at

Tags: c#, vector

I've been searching and searching, but fail to find the comparison. Is there a direct conversion, or are more groundwork required to make this work for C#?

What is the C# equivalent of the C++ std::vector::at?

Comment: `ElementAt(index)` for `IEnumerable<T>` (I've put `IEnumerable<T>` - the most general - since I don't know how you treat `vector` in your C# code)

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic type List for your purposes. Indexer method of this type throws exception in the case of invalid index (in other words, operator[] of list is analogue of vector::at)

Comment: So with histogram being an int array and row + col being position values (x,y), how would you propose I work my way around following C++ line: histogram[(int)image.at<uchar>(row, col)]++;

Comment: @WONDERGG, like that: `List<int> a = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }; a[0]++;`

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused, haven't worked that much with lists. Would 1,2,3 be my (x,y) coordinate, and where to I target my histogram array?

Comment: use this method of two dimensional list: `List<List<T>>` like that `some_list[0][0]`

Comment: I fail to find that method, and most people seem to disregard it fully. In what manner would you use it on the line I presented? I can post more of the project I'm working on, if it would help to get some more context. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`MyList.ElementAt(..)`/`MyEnumerable.ElementAt(..)` do bounds checking, as well as the plain `MyList[..]` 
 [See C# Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,0c65bec4d3fac21e,references)